# How to select a div in jquery and replace it with an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have jquery code which has been set up to select a 'div' called `wrap`.

What I want to do is change the selected 'div' to an 'iframe' with the the id `news`.

I have tried a few things and haven't managed to get it to work. Below is my code

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    var $wrap = $('#wrap'),
        page = 1;

    $('#next').on('click', function () {
        getPage(++page);
    });

    $('#prev').on('click', function () {
        getPage(--page);
    });

    var getPage = function (page) {
        $wrap.load('proxy.php?page=' + page + ' #postsArea');
    };

    getPage(page);

});
```

Below is the generated HTML

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
</div>
<button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
<button type="button" id="prev">Previous</button>
</body>
```

Below is what I want to change it to

```
<body>
<iframe id="news">
</iframe>
<button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
<button type="button" id="prev">Previous</button>
</body>
```

Comment: There isn't one mention of iframe in the code, so what have you tried?

Comment: Why would you want that? You can just load content into a div as you are doing already.

Comment: you need to change your iframe's src file request, you cannot simply load it into an iframe., what your doing here is using the jq load method not an iframe

Comment: Can you show your HTML please. Your questions asks **"what I want to do is change the selected 'div' to an 'iframe'"** and the answers you're getting don't address that, some answers assume `#news` is already an iframe. Is it?

Comment: as  popnoodles mentions you want to change <div id="wrap"></div> to <iframe id="news" src=...></iframe> is this correct, then answers below are showing how to load into that iframe but YOU want to cnage the current div to the iframe, correct?? Think it not best just to add the iframe? or use JQ load method

Comment: I updated my question with the 'HTML' I hope it helps.

Comment: Right so you DO want to change a div to an iframe!

Comment: Yes sorry about the confusion.

Comment: why can you not use an iframe from the onset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"what I want to do is change the selected 'div' to an 'iframe' with the the id news."**

This is how to do that, and give it the URL you want within the function you wrote.

```
var getPage = function (page) {
    $("#news").replaceWith($('<iframe>', {
        src:'proxy.php?page=' + page + ' #postsArea',
        id:'news'
    }));
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2qSAD/

Though as someone mentioned, it would be better to use an iframe in the first place. If you want to hide it until you need it (which could be why you're using a div) you can do that.

```
<iframe id="news" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

JQ

```
var getPage = function (page) {
    $("#news").prop('src', 'proxy.php?page=' + page + ' #postsArea').show();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('news').src = "proxy.php?page="+page+"#postsArea";
```

Comment: This is not what was asked

Comment: @popnoodles Then what was, if I may ask?

Comment: " what I want to do is change the selected 'div' to an 'iframe' with the the id news."

Comment: Fair enough, but surely you just open the HTML file, Ctrl+F the div, and replace it with an iframe? :p

Answer (score 1):

Use `src` attribute to change iframe source

```
$('#news').attr('src', "proxy.php?page="+page+"#postsArea")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace a complete element, I'd suggest to aim its parent:

```
$("#mydiv").parent().html("<iframe>....</iframe>");
```

html() returns the INNER html of an element. So the parent's inner is the element itself.

Comment: If you do this, you destroy the siblings of #mydiv

Comment: Correct, this only works if mydiv is the only child.

Answer (score 1):

could you not use the JQ query replaceWith..

```
  $( "div#wrap" ).replaceWith('<iframe id="news" src=".."></iframe);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using outerHTML:

```
document.getElementById("wrap").outerHTML="<iframe id='news'></iframe>";
```

Below is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/uZsmq/